# Counting all combinations of values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

The following is an example of items rated by 1,2 or 3 stars.
I am trying to count all combinations of item ratings (stars) per month.

In the following example, item 10 was rated in month 1 and has two ratings equal 1, one rating equal 2 and one rating equal 3.

```
inp = pd.DataFrame({'month':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                    'item':[10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20], 
                    'star':[1,2,1,3,3,2,2,3]}
                  )

 month item star
0   1   10  1
1   1   10  2
2   1   10  1
3   1   10  3
4   1   20  3
5   2   20  2
6   2   20  2
7   2   20  3
```

For the given above input frame output should be:

```
   month    item    star_1_cnt  star_2_cnt  star_3_cnt
0   1       10      2           1           1
1   1       20      0           0           1
2   2       20      0           2           1
```

I am trying to solve the problem starting with the following code,
which result still needs to be converted to the desired format of the output frame and which gives the wrong answers:

```
1   20  3   (1, 1)
2   20  3   (1, 1)
```

Anyway, there should be a better way to create the output table, then finalizing this one:

```
months = [1,2]
items = [10,20]
stars = [1,2,3]

d = {'month': [], 'item': [], 'star': [], 'star_cnts': [] }

for month in months:
    for star in stars:
        for item in items:
            star_cnts=dict(inp[(inp['item']==item) & (inp['star']==star)].value_counts()).values()
            d['month'].append(month)
            d['item'].append(item)
            d['star'].append(star)
            d['star_cnts'].append(star_cnts)
            
pd.DataFrame(d)

    month   item    star    star_cnts
0   1       10      1       (2)
1   1       20      1       ()
2   1       10      2       (1)
3   1       20      2       (2)
4   1       10      3       (1)
5   1       20      3       (1, 1)
6   2       10      1       (2)
7   2       20      1       ()
8   2       10      2       (1)
9   2       20      2       (2)
10  2       10      3       (1)
11  2       20      3       (1, 1)
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a nice problem for [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
new_df = (
    pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['star'])], axis=1)
    .groupby(['month', 'item'], as_index=False)
    [df['star'].unique()]
    .sum()
)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   month  item  1  2  3
0      1    10  2  1  1
1      1    20  0  0  1
2      2    20  0  2  1
```

Renaming, too:

```
u = df['star'].unique()
new_df = (
    pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['star'])], axis=1)
    .groupby(['month', 'item'], as_index=False)
    [u]
    .sum()
    .rename({k: f'star_{k}_cnt' for k in df['star'].unique()}, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   month  item  star_1_cnt  star_2_cnt  star_3_cnt
0      1    10           2           1           1
1      1    20           0           0           1
2      2    20           0           2           1
```

Obligatory one- (or two-) liners:

```
# Renames the columns
u = df['star'].unique()
new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['star'])], axis=1).groupby(['month', 'item'], as_index=False)[u].sum().rename({k: f'star_{k}_cnt' for k in df['star'].unique()}, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `value_counts` on the whole DataFrame and unstack:

```
out = (
 inp.value_counts()
    .unstack('star', fill_value=0)
 )
```

Alternatively, you can use `crosstab`.

As it requires 1D data as input, you can use tuples:

```
cols = ['month','item']
out = pd.crosstab(inp[cols].apply(tuple, axis=1), inp['star'])

out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(out.index, names=cols)
```

Output:

```
star        1  2  3
month item         
1     10    2  1  1
      20    0  0  1
2     20    0  2  1
```

###### formated output

This was already nicely demonstrated by @ansev

```
(inp.value_counts()
    .unstack('star', fill_value=0)
    .rename(lambda c: f'star_{c}_cnt', axis=1)
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
 )
```

Output:

```
   month  item  star_1_cnt  star_2_cnt  star_3_cnt
0      1    10           2           1           1
1      1    20           0           0           1
2      2    20           0           2           1
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to convert to dataframe

```
out = inp.value_counts()\
         .unstack('star', fill_value=0)\
         .rename(lambda x: f'star_{x}_cnt', axis=1)\
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

print(out)

   month  item  star_1_cnt  star_2_cnt  star_3_cnt
0      1    10           2           1           1
1      1    20           0           0           1
2      2    20           0           2           1
```

Comment: you dont need the groupby, `value_counts` should be sufficient

Answer (score 2):

One option, with pivot_table :

```py
(inp
.pivot_table(index=['month', 'item'], 
             values = 'star', 
             columns='star', 
             aggfunc='size', 
             fill_value = 0)
.rename(columns = lambda col: f"star_{col}_cnt")
.rename_axis(columns = None)
.reset_index()
)
   month  item  star_1_cnt  star_2_cnt  star_3_cnt
0      1    10           2           1           1
1      1    20           0           0           1
2      2    20           0           2           1
```

Another option, with groupby(pivot_table is a wrapper around groupby + unstack):

```py
(inp
.groupby(['month', 'item', 'star'])
.size()
.unstack(fill_value = 0)
.rename(columns = lambda col: f"star_{col}_cnt")
.rename_axis(columns = None)
.reset_index()
)

   month  item  star_1_cnt  star_2_cnt  star_3_cnt
0      1    10           2           1           1
1      1    20           0           0           1
2      2    20           0           2           1
```

Another option, with `pd.get_dummies` + `groupby`:

```py
(pd.get_dummies(inp, columns=['star'])
.groupby(['month', 'item'])
.sum()
.add_suffix('_cnt')
.reset_index()
)
   month  item  star_1_cnt  star_2_cnt  star_3_cnt
0      1    10           2           1           1
1      1    20           0           0           1
2      2    20           0           2           1
```

performance wise, only tests can tell - I'd expect pivot_table to be slower than the groupby